# Apollo Server Azure Functions - Change Sandbox Endpoint

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I'm using [Apollo Server with Azure Functions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/azure-functions/) and as of a [v3.8.0](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v380) there is a new `embed` option for the landing page plugin which allows the sandbox to be embedded into the server endpoint.

This is what my current config looks like

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: ({ context }) => context,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({
    embed: true
  })],
});

export default server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  },
});
```

I'd like to lock down the Function App in Azure by using Azure Active Directory and having any unauthenticated requests get rejected with 401: Unauthorized. The problem, however, is that would also deny access to the sandbox when trying to access it when deployed in Azure.

Is there a way to specify a separate sandbox endpoint that could allow unauthenticated requests? Then from the sandbox we could send in a `Authorization: Bearer ...` header to the actual graphql endpoint.